# calculation in javascript to overcome vertical-align:middle

Tags: jquery, html, css, if-statement

I am trying to write a function to

1. find the image height
2. perform a calculation (200px - image height)
3. add a css style to each different thumbnail ( `.imgk{margin-top:"calculated value";}` ).

I am unable to set a fixed value for `margin-top`, because the images vary in size. They are placed inside a individual `div`, which I have set `max-width` and `max-height` of 200x200 px. I thought if I can calculate and add the css to each image.

**Note**: I am trying to overcome `vertical-align:middle`, because the div is `display:block`. (for `display:table-cell`, vertical-align will work but image(div) will not change rows to fit within window.)

This is what I have now and chrome is saying "img" is not defined?

```
<div id="container_imgk">
    <div><a href="image-1.jpg"><img src="image-1.jpg" class="imgk"></a></div>
    <div><a href="image-2.jpg"><img src="image-2.jpg" class="imgk"></a></div>
</div>

<script>
var img_th = 0;//define the variable to 0 for each new image?

if ($("img").hasClass('imgk')) {//only apply the follow to img with class imgk
var img_th = $((200-$("img").height())/2);//the caluation
    $("img").css('margin-top',img_th);//add css to class imgk
});
</script>
```

Thank you very much.

Comment: You have more than one `img` element, so you will have to do that in a loop. Apart from that, I doubt that you actually need JS here; you should rather describe the real problem and show the exact code that is causing it.

Comment: You should really provide an online sample as jsFiddle replicating your issue, sounds really like a XY problem: http://mywiki.wooledge.org/XyProblem

Comment: thank you Gaby, CBroe, Wolff. I will try the suggested codes, and if it doesn't work. I will try to simplify the html to show you guys.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use

```
$('img.imgk').each(function(){
    var self = $(this),
        height  = self.height();

    self.css({
       'margin-top': (200 - height)/2
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

jQuery [.css()](http://api.jquery.com/css/#css-propertyName-function) method accepts a function as parameter, you could use:

```
$('img.imgk').css('margin-top', function(){
     return (200 - $(this).height()) / 2;
});
```

Comment: May I ask, what is the major difference of this code to Gaby's? (I don't mean to be rude. Just that I really don't have much knowledge in jquery and javascript).

Comment: this has same behaviour as Gaby's one just a little more compact. The reason i posted it was to show how you could use the jQuery `.css()` method

Answer (score 0):

You can try position:
http://api.jqueryui.com/position/

Example:

```
$('img.imgk').each(function(){
  $(this).position({
   my: "center",
   at: "center",
   of: "#targetElement"
  });
});
```